# JRebel Remote Installation on a Domino Server 12.0.2

Tags: osgi, xpages, lotus-domino, jrebel

I have a question concerning JRebel Remote Installation on a `Domino Server 12.0.2`

https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/remoteserver/eclipse.html#eclipseremoteserver

In the beginning it looked promising, jrebel seems to be installed correctly, but after restarting the server I got some xpages/osgi initialization errors:

**[image: strong text]**

notes.ini

```
JavaOptionsFile=D:\IBM\Domino\JRebelOptionsFile.txt
```

JRebelOptionsFile.txt

```
-agentpath:D:\jrebel\lib\jrebel64.dll -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance

### UPDATE:

I have done the same thing on a `Domino Server 12.0.1` without any troubles:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do something with the modified dll loading scheme in 12.0.2 as described [here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/12.0.2/admin/wn_other_enhancements.html):

> **C API OSLoadLibrary changes**
> On Windows, if a fully qualified path is not specified for a library to be loaded, the C API OSLoadLibrary no longer searches the path for the library.
>
> Instead, by default, this API searches the Notes or Domino executable directory, the Windows System directory, and the Windows directory. You can use notes.ini variables of the format OSLL_<#>= to specify up to five additional locations to search. For example:
> OSLL_3="d:\Application\Libraries".

You could try to add the dll path of JRebel to Domino using the notes.ini variable OSLL_1 as described in a similar issue regarding ScanMail for Domino [here](https://success.trendmicro.com/dcx/s/solution/000291870?language=en_US).

Comment: I have added the following entry `OSLL_1=D:\jrebel\lib\jrebel64.dll` without success.
**Hint:** I have updated my post regarding  `note.ini` jvm options.

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation and the example? This is a SEARCH PATH for DLLs, not a direct link to a dll... try `OSLL_1=D:\jrebel\lib\`

Comment: Thanks for your support. Changing the `notes.ini` entry to `OSLL_1=D:\jrebel\lib` doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Then I'm sorry... I have no more ideas

Comment: I have done the same thing on a `Domino Server 12.0.1` without any troubles